# git bash goes into an awkward state after using command "pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories"

Tags: git, bash, github

While using git bash when I try to merge files from remote repo to my local repo using the command-> "`git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`" , then it merges the files successfully but then the git bash goes into an awkward state, where all commands I type in git bash gets executed but does not show while typing. And only if I give reset command then the git bash comes back to normal stage. Is there any other way through (other than reset) or am I making any mistake? [git bash showing warning after pull command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUidv.png)

Comment: Since this isn't a real answer, I'll leave it as a comment, but often my experience with strange shell behavior fixed by a reset is caused by the poor handling of unicode characters. Does this happen with all repositories or only one?

Comment: I've had this in the past. While not optimal, restarting the shell solves the issue.

Comment: Does this happen with all repositories or only one? – yes whenever i use the pull command this happens.@Will Barnwell